# Monogame with winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, monogame, opentk

I'm planning on creating a map editor for a C# game I'm building. I've done this previously using XNA and XNA's old GraphicsDeviceControl, GraphicsDeviceService and ServiceContainer. I want the ability to create a class and inherit from the GraphicsDeviceControl class and then drag that class onto the form from the toolbox just like this: [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGsUdDI-_jA&feature=youtu.be&t=8m26s)

I've installed OpenTK using NuGet and followed this [tutorial](http://jaquadro.com/2013/03/bringing-your-xna-winforms-controls-to-monogame-opengl/) but when I create a class and inherit GraphicsDeviceControl it doesn't show up in the form toolbox. Am I doing something wrong? Isn't this possible using monogame? If it's possible, what should I do to get it working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's certainly possible, although I can't remember the exact details. I think I found a control in the SharpDX framework that can be adapted to work with MonoGame.

Comment: @craftworkgames Thanks, I'll take a look at SharpDX then

Comment: @craftworkgames Could you see if you can find the details? I've searched around a bit but I can't find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're working in Xamarin Studio on MacOS right?

Comment: @livin_amuk no, I'm working in Visual Studio 2015 on Win 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working :D
I added every class that exists in the project called MGWinFormsControls in [this](https://github.com/jaquadro/MonoGame-WinFormsControls) github repo to my project. I already had a monogame.framework as well as OpenTK and OpenTK.GlControl reference. Then I created a class and inherited from GraphicsDeviceControl. At first this didn't work but after only writing one line of code in the draw function in my class it worked. I just wrote GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black). Now the class shows up in the toolbox

Answer (score 0):

If your simply after a GL window within a form, look into `GLControl`, it does exactly that. Right click in some empty space of the Toolbox, browse and select `OpenTK.GLControl.dll`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wrote this earlier today, somehow deleted it, undeleted it for reference. Glad you got it sorted.